# How to test Vue 3 component with Pinia store in it

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, pinia

I started to learn testing, but have not yet achieved much success in this. I'm trying to write a mock test for a component, but I'm getting an error

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@/stores/store' from 'src/components/reusable/Header.vue'

    Require stack:
      src/components/reusable/Header.vue
      src/components/reusable/Header.test.ts

      42 | <script lang="ts" setup>
      43 | import { reactive, computed, onMounted } from "vue";
    > 44 | import { useStore } from "@/stores/store";
         | ^
      45 | import Button from "@/components/reusable/Button.vue";
      46 | import LocaleSwitcher from "@/components/reusable/LocaleSwitcher.vue";
      47 | import Moon from "@/assets/images/moon.svg";

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:487:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/reusable/Header.vue:44:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/reusable/Header.test.ts:2:1)
```

Here is my Vue 3 component

```
<template>
  <div class="menu">
    <Button
      v-show="width < 800 && store.hasGroup && !state.showMenu"
      class="custom-button_type_elevated burger-button"
      @click="showMenu"
    >
      <div class="burger-icon"></div>
    </Button>
    <nav
      v-if="store.hasGroup"
      class="navbar"
      :class="state.showMenu ? '' : 'navbar_hidden'"
      v-click-outside="closeMenu"
    >
      <Button
        class="custom-button_type_elevated menu-button"
        :button-text="$t('button.info')"
        :class="store.currentTab === 'information' ? 'custom-button_active' : ''"
        @click="goToPage('information')"
      />
      <Button
        class="custom-button_type_elevated menu-button"
        :button-text="$t('button.subs')"
        :class="store.currentTab === 'subscribers' ? 'custom-button_active' : ''"
        @click="goToPage('subscribers')"
      />
      <Button
        class="custom-button_type_elevated menu-button"
        :button-text="$t('button.reg')"
        :class="store.currentTab === '/' ? 'custom-button_active' : ''"
        @click="goToPage('/')"
      />
    </nav>
    <LocaleSwitcher class="locale-switcher" />
    <Button class="theme-button" @click="setTheme(store.theme)">
      <img class="theme-icon" :src="store.theme === 'dark' ? Moon : Sun" alt="theme icon" />
    </Button>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { reactive, computed, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "@/stores/store";
import Button from "@/components/reusable/Button.vue";
import LocaleSwitcher from "@/components/reusable/LocaleSwitcher.vue";
import Moon from "@/assets/images/moon.svg";
import Sun from "@/assets/images/sun.svg";
import { getWidth } from "@/composables/resizeController";

const store = useStore();
const width = getWidth();
const state = reactive({
  showMenu: false,
  wrapperClass: computed(() => (store.currentTab === "/" ? "" : "wrapper_dark")),
});
const goToPage = (page: string) => {
  store.currentTab = page;
  state.showMenu = false;
}
onMounted(() => {
  setTheme(store.theme);
});
const setTheme = (theme: string) => {
  document.documentElement.className = theme;
  store.theme = theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark";
};
const showMenu = () => {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    state.showMenu = true;
  }, 0);
}
const closeMenu = () => {
  if (state.showMenu) state.showMenu = false;
}
</script>
```

Here is my test

```
import Header from "./Header.vue";
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import { createTestingPinia } from "@pinia/testing";
import { useStore } from "@/stores/store";

describe("Counter Store", () => {
  const store = useStore();
  const wrapper = mount(Header, {
    global: {
      plugins: [createTestingPinia()],
    },
  });

  store.theme = "dark";

  expect(store.theme).toBe("dark");

  store.updateGroup();

  expect(store.updateGroup).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

I would appreciate any help. I myself read the testing documentation for Pinia, the documentation for Vue Test Utils, but I still don’t understand what generally depends on what and what happens inside. Tried many different code snippets from the net, but none of them helped with this problem. I don't have any preference for a testing library or a specific testing method, so I can change my approach, just don't know which way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you were TS in your project, had the exact same error in mine with testing and pinia.

Make sure to change all your **pinia** related files extensions from **.js** to **.ts**

Hope this helps someone.